# Batch file, command copy can't find directory

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have taht code

```
:instalation1
cls
echo.
echo ==============
echo = III        =
echo ==============
echo.
if %place%==1 (
    md C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SBI
    set folder=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SBI
    ) else (
            md \SBI
        set folder=\SBI
        )
cd %folder%
timeout>nul 2

:instalation 2
cls
echo.
echo ==============
echo = IIIIII     =
echo ==============
echo.
copy \data\SBI.bat %folder%\
timeout>nul 2
```

But when i run it, command copy is saying "System can't find that directory"
(folder "data" is in the same directory as batch file)

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the same drive as the batch file you are running on.

If you are on the E: drive and you run C:\data\batchfile or of C:\data is on the path then it will run the batch file from C:, but the working directory is on E: for the purpose of execution so E:\data doesn't exist.  As a test add a call to just CD to give you the current drive before the copy.

this is just a test to see if you are on the drive you expect to be on.

```
:instalation 2
cls
echo.
echo ==============
echo = IIIIII     =
echo ==============
echo.
cd 
copy \data\SBI.bat %folder%\
timeout>nul 2enter code here
```

Comment: I get to the answer aloe yesterday.  When i was typing xcopy \data\...  Computer was thinking about this C:\data\... If I want to copy something from folder data, and data is in the same directory as batch file command should Look like this xcopy data\...

Answer (score 0):

```
copy \data\SBI.bat %folder%\
```

you use an absolute path (:\data\sbi.bat).

Instead use a relative path:

```
copy data\SBI.bat %folder%\
```

Also to change the drive too with `cd`, use

```
cd /d %folder%
```

Comment: I would consider adding `%~dp0` just before `data`, to ensure that it will always pick the right path, regardless of CWD.